# Appropriateness of asking the group for a software evaluation

Tags: discussion

I'm about to get a web-based weight and balance program for 747s working. It's a free, open-source project that I've been working on for 3 years, primarily just an exercise to learn Javascript and keep my aging brain active (I'm 74). When it becomes usable, hopefully in the next few weeks, would it be appropriate to ask a question of the group concerning how understandable the user interface is and solicit suggestions for improvement?

Comment: Could you give amsome more detailed description on your project. You told us, that it's a web-based mass and balance calculation tool but what kind of features does it offer? You wrote, that it is "for 747s" is it a phrase or really developed to match the requirements of different Boeing 747 variants?

Comment: It sounds like the best place to possibly do this is in the chat, which I'll explore. I'm new here so haven't really gotten used to the site. In answer, though, to your comment, it's for any of the variants for which I have data, which at the moment means the -100, -200, and -400. The program is a redo of a public-domain DOS program I originally wrote in 1988 and is, I think, still used by 2 freight carriers. You can take a look at the current state of development at 747.terryliittschwager.com.

Comment: @Terry, would you mind joining us at the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar)? We'd be happy to have you there.

Comment: I just wanted to commend you for making this, it looks very good; you're brain definitely isn't aging, like you suggest!

Answer (score 7):

I think this would be very welcome in chat, but not as a question. Leaving aside the 'advertising' aspect, there could be no single, correct answer to the question anyway.

Answer (score 7):

This sort of thing strikes me as more something that would be appropriate for [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) than the main site -- evaluating software is an iterative process with lots of mini-feedback-loops and back-and-forth discussion, but not really a clear "answer".

We already have a pretty active group in Chat, and most of us have at least some level of technical background which means we could probably give good constructive feedback :)